# Why compiling Fortran MAIN__ object produces an error that duplicate definitions of MAIN__ exist?

Tags: makefile, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to compile an interface of two different softwares. This is what I am doing:

Since only the object files are available for software_1 and not the source files, two step process was followed to create the Makefile:

- (1) Objects were created for all the software_2 fortran routines and subroutines.
- (2) OBJ_ALL was additionally defined to lump all the objects together for the linking step.

Using this Makefile the objects of software_2 are linked with the objects of software_1 to create the executable.

The following error occurs when compiled:

```
"Makefile:422: warning: overriding recipe for target `../executable.e'
Makefile:411: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `../executable.e'

ifort *.o -o ../executable.e  -r8 -align common -w -O3 -Wl,--start-group  /opt/ohpc/pub/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a /opt/ohpc/pub/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a /opt/ohpc/pub/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -openmp -lpthread -lm

FILE.o: In function `MAIN__':

FILE.f:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MAIN__'
object.o:./OBJECT_source_code/object.F90:(.text+0x0): first defined here

make: *** [../executable.e] Error 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you have 2 objects with a main program (once in the object.F90 / object.o and once in FILE.f / FILE.o).

Comment: Welcome, use tag fortran for all Fortran questions. You should show your code or at the very least the cpmplete make output. Most likely it is a duplicate of some similar questions here. You might be compiling the main program twice or have it defined in two different files at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to pack all your object file (both 1 and 2) into a static library, then link your program 2 object file with this library.

something like ( on Linux, with `ar` installed )

```
lib.a: *.o
    ar cru $@ $^

../executable.e: object.o lib.a
    $(FC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

Comment: I agree that this is probably a good approach for solving the compilation error, but it seems awfully optimistic for the OP to suppose that anything like this is viable for producing a combined program with the behavior they hope to obtain.  Whatever that is.